# heroku --version returns error

Tags: linux, heroku, rhel

After installing Heroku CLI for RHEL, I am getting below error after running `herolu --version` command. What is the reason, how to solve this problem?

```
[xxxxx@oc3651178580 ~]$ heroku --version
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:3:in `require': /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:303: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
...de('utf-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace).sp...
                          ^
from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:3
from /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:18:in `require'
from /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue due to a 'old' version of ruby (1.8) set by default.
I've uninstall it and reinstall the latest one, and now it is working

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Use this to find out what it actually is:

```
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

Use this to find out what package it belongs to:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/ruby1.8
ruby1.8: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

Use this to uninstall that:

```
$ apt-get purge ruby1.8
```

Reisntall the lastest one

```
$ apt-get install ruby
```